# Materialize CSS Validate All Form Fields on Submit

Tags: javascript, css, html, materialize

I have a basic form built with the MaterializeCSS library. The form has some required fields like this (not my code but shows the problem perfectly):

https://codepen.io/zzzian/pen/LZbrOP

```
<div class="row">
<form class="col s12">
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <input id="email2" type="email" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
    <label for="email2">Email</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <input id="example" name="example" type="text" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
    <label for="example">Field</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <select required="" aria-required="true">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
        <label>Materialize Select</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Notice that when submit is clicked, only the **first** invalid field is displayed.

In my opinion this is really bad UX, as it potentially leaves the user having to perform multiple cycles of Enter->Submit->Correct until all form fields are correctly filled in.

What I want is for **ALL** invalid fields to be highlighted. This enables the user to correct all mistakes at once and then submit.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.